# How to delete shared remote git branches?

Tags: git, github

The contents of config file in my .git directory are like this:

```
     [core]
             repositoryformatversion = 0
             filemode = true
             bare = false
             logallrefupdates = true
             worktree = ../../src/PKGNAME
     [remote "origin"]
             url = ssh://git.COMPANYNAME.com:port/pkg/PKGNAME
             fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     [remote "backup"]
             url = ssh://git.COMPANYNAME.com:port/pkg/PKGNAME/backup/username
             fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/backup/*
             push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
     [remote "share"]
             url = ssh://git.COMPANYNAME.com:port/pkg/PKGNAME/share/username
             fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/share/*
             push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
     [branch "integTests"]
             remote = origin
             merge = refs/heads/mainline
             rebase = true
     [branch "clean"]
             remote = origin
             merge = refs/heads/mainline
             rebase = true
```

I ran git push and it shared all the local branches, even those which were not listed in this config file. The output was this:

```
   $ git push share
   Counting objects: 109, done.
   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (100/100), 6.70 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 100 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To ssh://git.COMPANYNAME.com:port/pkg/PKGNAME/share/username
    * [new branch]      clean -> clean
    * [new branch]      fresh -> fresh
    * [new branch]      integTests -> integTests
    * [new branch]      mainline -> mainline
```

I want to share only my mainline branch. How do I unshare the rest?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @janos that shows how to delete the erroneously pushed branches on the remote, you want to change your `push` specification for that remote so it looks like this:

```
[remote "share"]
         url = ssh://git.COMPANYNAME.com:port/pkg/PKGNAME/share/username
         fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/share/*
         push = +refs/heads/mainline:refs/heads/mainline
```

That way, the only branch `git push` will concern itself with when talking to the `share` remote is your `mainline` branch...

Edit: Incorporating advice from @janos on deleting erroneously pushed branches on the remote:

> You have to delete the others one by one:

```
git push share :clean
git push share :fresh
git push share :integTests
```